# BreezeJS - results from multiple linq queries into a single object

Tags: c#, linq, breeze, asp.net-web-api2, complextype

I'm wondering if it is possible to take the results of multiple queries, and append them into a collections object for breeze to query even further?

here's an example of what I mean and using the lookups detail as a reference:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/lookup-lists

WebAPIController:

```
[HttpGet]
public CollectionDTO Collection() {
    var _regions = _contextProvider.Context.Regions
                     .Select(x => new RegionsDTO { ID = x.ID, Text = x.Text});
    var _territories = _contextProvider.Context.Territories
                     .Join(_contextProvider.ContextRegions,
                           region => region.TerritoryID,
                           territory => territory.ID,
                          (region, territory) => new { region, territory))
                     .Select(x => new TerritoriesDTO { ID = x.ID, Text = x.Text});
    var _categories = _contextProvider.Context.Categories
                     .Select(x => new CategoriesDTO { ID = x.ID, Text = x.Text});

    var collection = new CollectionsDTO {
        Regions = _regions,
        Territories = _territories,
        Categories = _categories
    }

    return collection;
}
```

DTOs

```
public class CollectionsDTO {
    public IEnumerable<RegionsDTO> Regions;
    public IEnumerable<TerritoriesDTO> Territories;
    public IEnumerable<CategoriesDTO> Categories;    
}

public class RegionsDTO {
    public string ID;
    public string Text;
}

public class TerritoriesDTO {
    public string ID;
    public string Text;
}

public class CategoriesDTO {
    public string ID;
    public string Text;
}
```

How would I have BreezeJS query that would provide for me:

- The list of all Regions with ID and Text properties
- The list of all Territories with ID and Text properties and that starts with the letter C
- The list of all Categories selecting only the Text property ordered in ASC order?

Would something like this work?

```
    var queryRegion = breeze.EntityQuery
                            .from("Collection")
                            .select("Region.ID, Region.Text")

    var queryTerritory = breeze.EntityQuery
                            .from("Collection")
                            .Where("Territory.Text", FilterQueryOp.StartsWith, 'C') 
                            .select("Territory.ID, Territory.Text")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, most importantly because the controller endpoint does not return an `IQueryable`.

The point of bundling "lookups" into a single object delivered by a single endpoint is to reduce to one request what would otherwise be the many requests necessary to acquire many small objects of diverse types. It's a performance optimization.

What you're looking to do seems to me contrary to that intent.

I think you're better off exposing separate `IQueryable` endpoints for the target types and querying them individually.

Comment: Thanks Ward. I wanted the lookup because of the optimization features. I had multiple queries that depend on the results of another; meaning I had a query that'd return a list of "Customers" based on a selection criteria, then I'd use that list to filter another separate list of Products belonging to those customers. I didn't want to get the list of Customers to display on the page, then a post of that list of Customers back to the server to get the list of related Products. I wanted a single shot. But in the end, I had no choice but to do everything in C#.